# How to I access upstream modules or shared resources in rust?

Tags: rust

As seen below I need App 0 and 1 to have access to app 2 and all the apps need to have access to Data.file in the Main_folder. How do I access upstream data??

The hierarchy Looks something like this :

```
Main_folder
|- App_folder_0
  |- src
     |- main.rs
|- App_folder_1
  |- src
     |- main.rs
|- App_folder_2
  |- src
     |- main.rs
|- Data.file
```

Comment: To clarify: is Data.file *next to* Main_folder or is it *in* main folder? The diagram makes it look like next to.

Comment: @njha in the Main_folder

Comment: How are you loading `Data.file`? Is it used at compile time or runtime? If it is at runtime, how are you running the applications, and can you rely on the working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is vague - any file can be accessed in a parent directory with std::fs::read.  If you are wanting to access a module in the parent path, this can be done easily, an example:

```rs
#[path = "../../my_module.rs"]
mod my_module;
```

Comment: I've seen many questions on this site that stem from improper use of `#[path = ...]`, I would not recommend using it unless you have no other choice. There's better mechanisms that would fit OP's structure.

Comment: @kmdreko what do you recommend??

Comment: If the applications will remain static in their directory structure, I see no issue using path, and have used it in multiple projects.   Module reference here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute.  Having said that, a few more involved options available include creating a local crate, which basically does the same thing on a project level (https://readlnh.github.io/2020/09/22/Rust/local_unpublished_crate_in_Rust/) or (if using git) adding your shared library as a git submodule to your application.